# Customize dc.js date x-axis

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Using bar chart:

```
actionsChart /* dc.barChart('#volume-month-chart', 'chartGroup') */
    .width(actionsWidth)
    .height(240)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(dateDimension)
     //...
    .elasticX(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .gap(1)
    .alwaysUseRounding(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain( [ minDate,  maxDate ] ) )
    .round(d3.time.day.round)
    .xUnits(d3.time.days)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    //.xAxisLabel( 'Dan')
    //.xAxisPadding(2)
    .xAxisLabel( "Datum")
    //.yAxisLabel( "Akcije" ) // OK, but already in title
    .xAxisPadding(1)
    //nok in dc: //.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"))
    //.label( function(d){ return JSON.stringify(d); })
    ;
```

It gets Label on x-axis unreadable (too much characters next to each other. 
[image: Too narrow x -axis label]

How to put label each 5 or 7 days, and customize format (day in month number, no week day) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

dc.js mostly uses d3v3's `d3.svg.axis` to draw its axes.

You may be looking for [`d3.svg.axis.ticks()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#ticks) and [`d3.svg.axis.tickFormat()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickFormat).

You can get at the d3 axis object that dc.js uses by calling `chart.xAxis()` but I advise doing it in a separate statement from your other chart initialization because [it gets confusing when you you chain function calls but they return different objects](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis).

So, something like (untested):

```
chart.xAxis()
    .ticks(d3.time.days, 7)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%e'));
```

[d3v3 time formatting specifiers](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format)

If you can't get the automatic tick generator to do what you want, you can always specify the exact list of ticks using [`.tickValues()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues). You'd want to do this before each render and redraw, so (again, untested):

```
function calc_ticks(chart) {
    var ticks = d3.time.weeks(chart.xAxisMin(), chart.xAxisMax()); // or days(chart.xAxisMin(), chart.xAxisMax(), 5)
    chart.xAxis().tickValues(ticks);
}
chart.on('preRender', calc_ticks)
    .on('preRedraw', calc_ticks);
```

Comment: Yes, separating ticks setting helps. Currently, for some reason, there are times that text overlaps with 1st of next month (which is displayed automaticaly). I am testing if text direction can help using CSS as mentioned in comments  in http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe that d3 looks at the text size at all when placing ticks. (That would be difficult and expensive.) Rotating the text can help, or if worse comes to worst you could calculate exactly the tick dates you want and use [`.tickValues()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md#tickValues).

Comment: Is there a way to disable display on 1st of the month ?

Comment: I think you need to disable automatic tick generation and use `.tickValues()` for that. I've added this to my answer.