# dc.js d3.js ElasticX with date values not rendering correctly when filtered

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Attempted to follow this example
[Customize dc.js date x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004978/customize-dc-js-date-x-axis)

here:
https://codepen.io/rdavi10471a2/pen/EeYYGB

as follows:

```
    function calc_ticks(chart) {
        var ticks = d3.timeMonths(chart.xAxisMin(), chart.xAxisMax()); 
        console.log("min: "+chart.xAxisMin()+' Max:'+chart.xAxisMax())
         console.log("ticks")
        console.log(ticks)
        chart.xAxis().tickValues(ticks);
   }
```

Initial rendering is correct but when you use the dc.js filter to filter to a single year the x axis does not render correctly.
January for the year chosen is not selected to be in the ticks array so all other ticks are off by one element. I have filtered to 2018 here
[image]
If you use the mouseover you will see that the last tick is 2018-08

unsure why this is happening another interesting thing is if you modify the minimum date  using moment.js like this

```
 var ticks = d3.timeMonths(moment(chart.xAxisMin()).subtract(1, 'months'), chart.xAxisMax());
```

it initially shows this
[image]

but on filtering shows this:

[image]

I am not sure what this implies but it is curious.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is the way you create the dates.

You iterate over all the months from 2017-01-01 till 2018-now-01 and create new dates based on this

```
datenotime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0);
```

Month has a range of 0..11, month 12 does not exist in JS and Day has a range 1..31, day 0 does not exist.

If you change that to

```
datenotime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
```

is equal to

```
datenotime = date;
```

The ticks on the x-axis are drawn at the Year-Month-01 and to make that more clear change the modification of the tick text positioning.

```
salesbymonth.renderlet(function (chart) {
    // ....
    chart.selectAll('g.x text')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(5,5) rotate(-90)')
        .attr('dx', "-0.5em")
        .attr('dy', "-0.7em")
        .style('font-weight',"bold")
        .style('font-size',"12px")
        .style('text-anchor',"end");
});
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  The (0) was because I was attempting to change the date to be the last day of the month and not the first. I will use moment Js for that in the future.  I was wrongly thinking the axis values did not line up because of the time component so I was trying to remove it... Live and Learn.

Comment: @RichardDavison : to get the last day of the month: get the date of next month first day (keep watch on Dec-Jan) and then subtract 1 day of ms and create a new Date

Answer (score 1):

```
   //   datenotime = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()+1, 0)
       datenotime = date  
 //add a month so that the last point gets a tick mark
  var ticks = d3.timeMonths(chart.xAxisMin(), 
              moment(chart.xAxisMax()).add(1,'months'));
```

this change fixed the issue.